# Method must have signature "String method() ...[etc]..." but has signature "void method()"

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf, el, eclipse-wtp

I have a datatable with a button in each row:

```
<ice:dataTable ... var="item">
  <ice:column>
    <h:commandButton value="Download" action="#{mybean.downloadItem(item)}" />
  </ice:column>
</ice:dataTable>
```

In the backing bean there's this method:

```
public void downloadItem(Item item) {
    // ...
}
```

Everything works fine (when clicked the method is executed), but
Eclipse validation fails with this strange message:

> Method must have signature "String method(), String method(), String
>   method(String), String method(String, String), String method(String,
>   String, String), String method(String, String, String, String), String
>   method(String, String, String, String, String), String method(String,
>   String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String),
>   String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String
>   method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String
>   method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,
>   String, String, String)" but has signature "void method()"

What can I do?

If that's relevant, I'm using Eclipse Indigo SR1 on Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Ignore it. Eclipse is a jerk. You can tone it by setting *Window > Preferences > Web > JavaServer Faces Tools > Validation > Type Assignment Problems > Method expression signature incompatibility* to *Warning* or *Ignore* (it defaults to *Error*).

[image]

<sup>Image borrowed from [this blog](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2014/10/jsf-22-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-wildfly.html) in all courtesy.</sup>

The reason is, Eclipse expect the `action` attribute to always return `String`, not `void`. Whilst indeed unspecified in JSF `action` attribute, the EL method expressions themselves actually also support `void` methods. The overzealous message in turn suggests that the underlying logic responsible for this validation is incapable of determining the individual method arguments and thus it tries to compare the raw method signature against a collection of allowed signatures, which ultimately get shown in the message if no match was found. Based on the message, this problem may also disappear when the method has 20 or more arguments ;)

This is fixed in Eclipse Luna SR1, nearly 6 years after the issue was reported. The severity has been decreased from *Error* to *Warning*. You may still want to put it yet lower to *Ignore*.

#### See also:

- [Eclipse issue report 243674](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243674)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: thanks - you're a real genius :-) and I fully agree on your Eclipse verdict ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, this error was very frustrating... also I see that you're the same person who wrote those awesome tutorials I'm following, so thank you for that as well.

Comment: FYI: under IBM's pressure this Eclipse issue has *finally* been fixed this month.

Comment: @BalusC good it's fixed, sad it needed pressure from IBM. Clearly WTP developers don't use their own tools to build JSF apps!

Comment: Based on your impressive answer, I believe changing the method signature to `public String downloadItem(Item item) { ...; return null; }` would make Eclipse happy without any change in app behavior, right?