# Error in jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

i am working on a java project. in that i used some jsp pages , there is an error in action attribute as follows_

```
<h:commandLink id="update_account_balance" rendered="false" 
    action="#{AccountHelperBean.updateAccountBalanceForOneTimeUse}">
    <h:outputText value="Update All Account's Balance" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

at the action attribute showing error like "*Method must have signature "String method()" but has signature "void method()"*" 
I am using Eclipse Indigo.
is anybody know about this kind of issue.
Thank u.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/validation-error-on-valid-facelet-when-calling-action-method-with-parameter

Comment: i would refer you to this [link][1], it might answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/validation-error-on-valid-facelet-when-calling-action-method-with-parameter

Comment: This is not JSP, it looks like JSF.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis Yes it helped me. tnx