# JSF action method

Tags: jsf, action

As mentioned in the link http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html,
it is passing parameter to method call , action="#{bean.edit(item)}"

But in my jsf i am getting error as Method must have signature "String method()" but has signature "void method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation error on valid facelet when calling action method with parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/validation-error-on-valid-facelet-when-calling-action-method-with-parameter)

Comment: In other words, don't stare blind on IDE-specific validation errors.