# JSF Epic EL Warning, should I worry?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces, el

I'm Developing a Liferay protlet that works with JSF 2 and PrimeFaces (3.5). I'm using Eclipse, and when I enabled in the Project Facets, the  'Java Server Faces', I'm getting this amazing error

```
    Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Syntax error in EL
- Method must have signature "String method(), String method(String), String method(String, String), String method(String, String, String), String method(String, String, 
 String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, 
 String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, 
 String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, 
 String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, 
 String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, 
 String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, 
 String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, 
 String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), String method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, 
 String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)" but has signature "String method(ABC)"
```

the xhtml code that causes that is :

```
<p:column headerText="Some Column Headed">  
    <h:outputText value="#{ mysteryBean.getABCName(widgetVarInstanceOfClassABC)}" />  
</p:column>
```

And the BackingBean's (@ManagedBean) code (referenced above as mysteryBean) is :

```
public String getABCName(ABC abc) throws Exception{
    // Used to get something that is not available through the get functions of ABC Class 
    // Do stuff related to the instance...
    return something;       
}
```

So far, my code works just fine without any troubles whatsoever.
I know that there are issues with Eclipse EL syntax and validation, but I'm not sure it's just that or I did something wrong. Should I worry or not ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ignore it.

The method signature validation doesn't work properly for Facelets pages. You can disable the validation in Eclipse preferences, see [Method must have signature "String method() ...[etc]..." but has signature "void method()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/validation-error-on-valid-facelet-when-calling-action-method-with-parameter?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: No one had ever reported this anywhere? Are the Eclipse developers even aware of this?

Comment: @dextermeyers , Yes, it's reported : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243674, back in 2008!