# jsf 2 passing method expression for "value" element

Tags: jsf, expression, el

i have a problem with jsf 2.0 and method expressions:

```
<ui:repeat var="attachment" value="#{bean.attachments}">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.aFunction(attachment)}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

but it already tells me when typing that "Method must have signature "String method(), String method(String), String method(String, String), String 
 method(String, String, String),..."

here is my function:

```
public String aFunction(Attachment a){
    return Functions.getFormattedAttachmentString(a);
}
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation error on valid facelet when calling action method with parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/validation-error-on-valid-facelet-when-calling-action-method-with-parameter)

Comment: hi, its not a duplicate; the thing is that these expressions work fine if i use them for an action (like in your link); but as value it screams;

eclipse makes a bit red "X" to the left, so this shoudl be an error right?

Comment: Have you actually tried to deploy it? If so, did it throw an error?

Comment: There is no error when i start the app and access the problematic site. but eclipse still unterlines it red and tells me there is one huge problem. can I tell Eclipse anyhow that this is OK?*