# h:commandButton is not working once I wrap it in a <h:panelGroup rendered>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, jsf-2.2, commandbutton

The reason why the topic has "kind of" is because I have an example in JSF 2.2 where I use a commandButton and call a bean function twice (depending on the url). It's basically the same code, which executes only in one example.

Here's the code with the description of the "error" below the code:

User bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class User {

private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;
private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public User(String name, String surname, int age, int id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.id = id;
}

public User(){}

}
```

UsersBean bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UsersBean {

private List<User> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
private String passedParameter;

public UsersBean() {
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Tywin", "Lannister", 60, 1));
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Tyrion", "Lannister", 30, 2));
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Jaime", "Lannister", 31, 3));
    listOfUsers.add(new User("Cercei", "Lannister", 29, 4));
    listOfUsers.add(new User("John", "Snow", 31, 5));
}

public List<User> getAll() {

    System.out.println("getAall is called.");
    return listOfUsers;
}

public User getDetails() {
    passedParameter = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("userID");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(passedParameter);
    User selected = null;
    for (User u : listOfUsers) {
        if (u.getId() == id) {
            selected = u;
        }
    }
    return selected;
}

public String addUser(User u) {
    System.out.println("addUser is called.");
    if (u.getId() != 0) {
        for (User edit : listOfUsers) {
            if (edit.getId() == u.getId()) {
                System.out.println("Found it!");
                edit.setAge(u.getAge());
                edit.setName(u.getName());
                edit.setSurname(u.getSurname());
            }
        }

    } else {
        u.setId(listOfUsers.size() + 1);
        listOfUsers.add(u);
    }

    return "";
}
}
```

users.xhtml:

```
    <f:view>
        <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/method-must-have-signature-string-method-etc-but-has-signature-void -->
        <h:dataTable value="#{usersBean.all}" var="u">

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    User ID
                </f:facet>
                    #{u.id}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Name
                </f:facet>
                    #{u.name}
            </h:column> 

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Details
                </f:facet>

                <h:link outcome="users" value="edit user">
                    <f:param name="userID" value="#{u.id}"></f:param>
                    <f:param name="action" value="edit"></f:param>
                </h:link>

                &nbsp;

                <h:link outcome="usersDetails" value="get details">
                    <f:param name="userID" value="#{u.id}"></f:param>
                </h:link>                   
            </h:column> 

        </h:dataTable>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param['action'] == 'edit'}">
            <h1>Edit!</h1>
            <h:form>
                <ui:param name="editUser" value="#{usersBean.details}"></ui:param>
                <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{editUser.name}"></h:inputText> <br />

                <h:outputText value="Surname"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{editUser.surname}"></h:inputText> <br />

                <h:outputText value="Age"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{editUser.age}"></h:inputText> <br />

                <h:commandButton action="#{usersBean.addUser(editUser)}" value="Edit" type="submit">    </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty param['action']}">
            <h1>Add!</h1>
            <h:form>
                <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{user.name}"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Surname"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{user.surname}"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Age"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{user.age}"></h:inputText>
                <h:commandButton action="#{usersBean.addUser(user)}" value="Add" type="submit"></h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>     

    </f:view>
```

OK, so, everything works perfectly. usersBean.addUser adds the user. If I add another inputText for ID and I put in an existing ID, the corresponding function updates the values. So, addUser function works as expected.

The problem is in case of

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{param['action'] == 'edit'}">
```

as you can see in the xhtml above, the code is basically the same, with the sole exception that I fill in the data of the user that was selected. This works, I get the appropriate data into input fields, but when I change them and click Edit, nothing happens. The function is not called! whereas in case of add, the function is called and it works.
It appears as if there is no action defined in case of edit, it only reloads the page (submit) without the actual action addUser.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `#{param['action'] == 'edit'}` didn't evaluate `true` during processing the form submit and therefore the `<h:panelGroup>` is basically not rendered during processing the form submit, including the `<h:commandButton>` sitting in there. The form submit namely did not pass that parameter back to JSF. This way JSF won't see the `<h:commandButton>` and therefore never be able to decode and queue its action event. You need to make sure that all your `rendered` conditions evaluate the same during processing the form submit as they were during displaying the form (this is part of JSF's safeguard against tampered/hacked requests wherein the enduser would otherwise be able to execute unrendered command buttons like admin-only buttons).

So, you basically need to retain that parameter during the postbacks as well so that the `rendered` expression still evaluates `true` during processing the form submit. This can be achieved in several ways:

1. Add it as `<f:param>` inside the `<h:commandButton>` of relevance:

   ```
   <h:commandButton action="#{usersBean.addUser(editUser)}" value="Edit" type="submit">
       <f:param name="action" value="#{param.action}" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```

   *(note: `param['action']` and `param.action` are equivalent; those brackets are only useful if the `'action'` contains periods, or represents another variable)*
2. Set it as a bean property by `<f:viewParam>`. Requirement is that the bean needs to be in view scope or broader. You've it in the session scope already, which is okay ([but which is IMO way too broad, but that aside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)):

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="action" value="#{usersBean.action}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ...
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{usersBean.action}">
       ...
   </h:panelGroup>
   ```
3. If you're already using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), use its `<o:form>` instead of `<h:form>` which enables you submit to the current request URI instead of to the current JSF view ID. This way the GET request string will automagically be retained and you don't need to copypaste `<f:param>` over all command buttons like as in #1:

   ```
   <o:form useRequestURI="true">
       ...
   </o:form>
   ```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - point 6